# How to send and open a variable web address to a object tag on a separate page using PHP?

Tags: php

in my test page I have three links which assign a different web address to a variable called $link

```css
.buttonpush {
 height: 25px;
 width: 200px;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #333;
 border: 2px solid #CCC;
}
.butdiv {
 position: absolute;
 left: 20px;
 top: 30px;
}​
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>index</title>
<link href="css/phptest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="butdiv">
<div class="buttonpush"><a href="show.php
?link=http://www.google.co.uk/">Button one</a></div>
<div class="buttonpush"><a href="show.php
?link=http://www.blue-seahorse.com/">Button two</a></div>
<div class="buttonpush"><a href="show.php
?link=http://www.blue-seahorse.com/">Button three</a></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
​
```

I need to make the result page display the required web site within the object tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>show</title>
</head>

<body>

   <?php
  $link = $_GET['link'];
  
  ?>
  
  <object data="echo htmlspecialchars '$link';" width="1000" height="720">
        <embed src="echo htmlspecialchars '$link';" width="1000" height="720" /> Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
    </object>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Although the correct web address is passed to the show.php page, it doesn't display the webpage being called. I've used a similar code to pass specific variable strings to a form before, but I failed in my attempt to achieve this result.

Comment: Your references are invalid. That should show up in your http servers error log file. That always is the first place to look in case of an issue. URLs may not contain other URLs like that. You have to escape the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
<object data="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($link); ?>" width="1000" height="720">
        <embed src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($link); ?>" width="1000" height="720" /> Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
    </object>
```

In order to use php variable it has to be inside `<?php  ?>`

Comment: Im glad that i could help :-)

Comment: Yikes Redrif !! just realised I misspelt your name!!  apologies!!  and thanks again!!  the code you helped me with will be used to open about 30 to 40 different specification pages for electronic components from different suppliers but I will now be able to keep everything within the confines of my website :-)